# C# ASP.NET List View

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a view with multiple product listing in it. An example is below of how the product listing should look like. I am not sure if I should use a table and create a new table for each new product or what. I am not a very good ASP.NET developer and I am not sure how to approach this.

Basically if I have 10 results I need to display 10 of these in a list and each button and image is different based on each product result.

The source of data is from another class that was built and runs through a foreach for each product. Any guidance on this would be helpful. I just think I need to be pointed in the right direction because I tried it with a table and it wasn't working out to well.

[image: Product List Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="myGrid" 
    OnRowCommand="MyGrid_RowCommand">
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img src='<%# Eval("SmallImageUrl") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>Title: <%# Eval("Title") %>  </div>
        <div>Weight: <%# Eval("Weight") %>  </div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="GetOfferButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OfferID") %>'></asp:Button>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Assuming you have a collection of Products e.g. List, or DataTable of Product etc., and your collection has these fields

```
class Product
{
   //property Title
   //property SmallImageUrl
   //property Weight
}
```

You can have

```
myGrid.DataSource = <Replace with List of Products collection>;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using asp.net table and just add rows with the images dynamically once you iterate your results..check out the control here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx

and here you have an example to add rows dynamically:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

in each row you can put the controls that you want...