# Pass an ID on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code below that create rows and cells for a list of products. There is a button that I want to use to get additional product information. Basically the user will search for something and it will display limited results. When the user clicks on the button it will call a method that will do something else.

How do I get that button to pass and ID or something to a method?

I tried the `.Click` but did not work to call the method. Currently the method only displays a messagebox.

```
for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++)
{
    // Create new row and add it to the table.
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
    Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
    for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++)
    {
        // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
        TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

        if (rowCtr == 1 && cellCtr == 1)
        {
            Image ProductImage = new Image();
            ProductImage.Height = 75;
            ProductImage.Width = 75;
            tCell.RowSpan = 5;
            tCell.Controls.Add(ProductImage);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }

        if (rowCtr == 1 && cellCtr == 2)
        {
            tCell.Text = "Title: Title of Product";
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }

        if (rowCtr == 2 && cellCtr == 2)
        {
            tCell.Text = "Weight (lbs): 54";
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }

        if (rowCtr == 4 && cellCtr == 2)
        {
            Button getOfferButton = new Button();
            getOfferButton.Width = 100;
            getOfferButton.Text = "Get Offer";
            getOfferButton.Click += new EventHandler(getOffer);
            tCell.Controls.Add(getOfferButton);

            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `<asp:GridView />` control instead of generating this with markup. One way to handle this is use the `OnCommand` event and pass the ID as argument

```
getOfferButton.Click += new CommandEventHandler(RowButton_OnCommand);
getOfferButton.CommandArgument = "123";
```

and then the Handler

```
protected void RowButton_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   string id = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); //could convert this to integer

}
```

Comment: I will have to try this in the morning. I was trying to get this to work with `<asp:Gridview />` but had better luck with tables. Please feel free to comment on my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204735/c-sharp-asp-net-list-view

Answer (score 0):

### First you need to return object list from your code behind , second you need to import ur BLL or BO what ever is name:

```
 '<asp:Repeater ID="rptGrpAcc" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptAccident_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="cursor: pointer" onclick="SelectGrpAcc(this,<%#Eval("ID"%>);">
              </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeter>'

     <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRowNum" runat="server" />
           <asp:Button ID="btnShowRptDtl" runat="server" Text="ShowRptDtl" Style="display: none"
             OnClick="btnShowRptDtl_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>

      ' <script type="text/javascript">
         /*---------------for selecting row of repeator--------*/
          function SelectGrpAcc(obj, ID) {
        
          document.getElementById("<%=hdnRowNum.ClientID %>").value = ID;
         document.getElementById("<%=btnShowRptDtl.ClientID %>").click();
    }'


'protected void btnShowRptDtl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           btnAdd.Text= "update";
      
          int Sn = ClsConvertTo.Int32(hdnRowNum.Value); // this is your ID in code behind 
       //   add logic here
       }'
```